# Gravity-neutralising biological adaptation

Tags: physics, xenobiology

So, the end-point I want to work towards is a creature that lives on a high-gravity planet that has some sort of adaptation that neutralises the effects of that high gravity, ideally in a way that could offer respite from the high gravity for a human riding that creature.

One thought I had was if part of the creature could generate vibrations that move upwards, to counteract the downward force of gravity, both for the creature itself, and for anything immediately on top of the creature. I have no idea if that would work however, or if it'd be practical for an organism to have this ability.

The adaptation doesn't need to have naturally evolved, but I want something that could believably have been genetically engineered.

Comment: Does the human have to ride on top? Or would being swallowed be allowed?

Comment: Gravity isn't really posible to be canceled. Or the creature would end up used as a spacecraft motor

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Partial swallowing might be okay... I'd still want the rider to be able to see where they're going and to steer the creature.

Answer (score 4):

Ride in a big mouth pouch.

Taking a bath in spit sounds bad, but gravity is much less of a problem when you are floating; the pressure is distributed evenly across the total submerged surface.

If the creature has a bathtub like mouth filled with something about as dense as a human (salt water) the human can lounge much more comfortably even with higher gravity.

Comment: Now I have "come and take a ride in my big mouth pouch" playing in my head.  But is that even a song??

Answer (score 3):

The planet could emit a strong magnetic field (which isn't unlikely if it's more massive and still capable of supporting life).

The creature could emit its own magnetic field opposite to the planets.

All it would need is to be able to make a lot of electricity ( eel on steroids).
And a strong metallic composition or organelles that when charged create your opposing force to gravity.

Note: no matter what you do the human is toast.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to conceive of a believable solution involving *gravitics.*  However, so long as you're not married to a gravitic solution:

**Gas**

The creature could have a bladder inflated with a lighter-than-air gas that allows it to float in the atmosphere.  Wings would provide propulsion.

**Alloyed bones, enhanced muscles**

A creature that can already fly in the atmosphere of said planet could be modified to strengthen bones and muscles to carry loads.

**The Anne McCaffrey Solution**

Finally, how scientifically-based does this need to be?  McCaffrey's *Dragon Riders of Pern* books have people riding dragons.  You can't get much more scientifically unbelievable — but she sold a boatload of books.  A giant bird with wings that naturally evolved on the planet solves your problem without the hoopla.